# WPF DataGrid override the selection color of a single row from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to change the color of a **single row** in a `DataGrid` from the code behind, even if the row is selected and therefore already changed color.

If the row is not selected I can just use:

```cs
((DataGridRow)row).Background = Brushes.Orange;
```

This works fine, but when the row is selected the orange color doesn't show over the blue selection color. How can I set a color to show over the selection for a single row (not the whole `DataGrid`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `Background` of the cells:

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
    var row = ...;

    foreach (DataGridCell cell in FindVisualChildren<DataGridCell>(row))
        cell.Background = Brushes.Orange;
}

private static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
                yield return (T)child;

            foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                yield return childOfChild;
        }
    }
}
```

Having said that, you should still prefer to define custom styles in XAML instead of modifying properties of visual containers programmatically.

Comment: Thnx, I understand. I will look into using styles. I'll have to figure out how to activate a style if the row contains an item that is somewhere in a list in the code behind :) But your answer made it clear that I have to look at the cell background instead of the row background.